# Hide/Show teams in left navigation bar of the MS Teams application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We would like to hide teams for the users in the left navigation bar of their MS Teams application programmatically. We would like to hide teams on behalf of the users in their application. Please see below image for the reference.

[image]

I couldn't get any graph API to do this. I don't know if it's feasible or not.

Is there any way to do this using MS Graph API or any other SDKs?

Answer (score 1):

Currently this feature is not available, Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in Teams [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) here, if this needs to be consider as a future request.